# Change forecolor of specific cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to change the forecolor of a specific cell in datagridview. I want to give different colors to different cells in the same row.

```
grid.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Using the above will change all the Row color and not just the cell I want to change.

Is there a way to change color of specific cell solely - not affecting other cells of the row?

It seems like I need to change some Row property that I am not familiar with.

Comment: Your code works for me, changing a single cells forecolor.

Answer (score 2):

> Using the above will change all the Row color and not just the cell I want to change

No, this is not correct. It will only change the text color (Forecolor) of the cell at the specified index.

You need to check that you are not setting the forecolor of row somewhere else in your code.

following code works fine for Changing the back and forecolor

```
//this will change the color of the text that is written
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;

//this will change the background of entire cell
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: @downvoter may i know the reason for the downvote? The code i have posted is tested and runs perfectly fine.

Comment: I am not sure if it is by design or what, but I am getting the same problem as the OP. I have a DataGridView bound to a table of a DataSet, and was setting the style in RowsAdded. RowsAdded was being called once for row 0 and then once again for rows 1-7. If I set the style for row 0 it would then for some reason be copied down to the other rows. If I set the style for any of the other rows it would work as described.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the Style or set Row.DefaultStyle  immediately after loading the default data(datagridview.Datasource=Table),
it will not affect until you load grid next time.

(ie if you set style in load event.It wont get affected.But if you call the same function again like after clicking button or something it will work)

Work around for this :

Set the style in DatagridView_DataBindingComplete event. It will work fine and change the color you can also

Comment: Surprisingly this is actually the answer. I was setting the style in RowsAdded which for some reason was being called twice, once for row 0 then once again for the rest. If I happened to set the style for row 0 it would apply to ALL the rest of the rows. Setting the style in DataBindingComplete instead fixed it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CellFormatting event:

```
void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewCell cell = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
   if (cell.Value is double && 0 == (double)cell.Value) { e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
}
```

in if you can write your condition to find specific cell.

or try this one.

```
private void ColorRows()
   {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewTest.Rows)
     {
       int value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
       row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = GetColor(value);
     }
   }

   private Color GetColor(int value)
   {
     Color c = new Color();
     if (value == 0)
       c = Color.Red;
     return c;
   }

   private void dataGridViewTest_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
   {
     ColorRows();
   }
```

Comment: probably source from [link] http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/203791/Changing-fore-color-of-a-dataGridView-cell

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
dgv.Rows[curRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```